# What to mention in the visa application form for the issuing authority of passport while applying for UK Transit visa from India

Tags: uk, transit-visas, passport-stamps

What to mention in the visa application form in the section for issuing authority of passport while applying for UK Transit visa from India? is it the officer who signed the passport when we open it?

Comment: Check in your passport. It could just be the government of India, the Kochi passport authority, or the XZ.4xz zone, never the real person (note: I made up the authorities, take it just as example). I think it is most important for emergency or special passports, passport issued in an embassy and occupied zone and war passports. Personally I write just the country (I have a regular passport)

Answer (score 4):

The issuing authority on Indian passport is mentioned below the name of the person whose signature are present.

For passports issued in India, it is something like, "Regional Passport Office, Delhi", "Regional Passport Office, Kolkata", etc.

For passports issued outside India, it would be something like "Consulate General of India, San Francisco", "High Commission of India, London", etc.

Answer (score 1):

The "issuing authority" is the government agency or department that issued the passport. For example, in the United States, passports are issued by the Department of State.

A brief Google search reveals that [Indian passports are issued by the Ministry of External Affairs](https://passportindia.gov.in/).

Comment: Although its technically correct, the right answer for the box is from which office it was issued. I have filled out numerous forms with this and it worked fine.

Comment: @AnishSheela What about the reverse case: do you know of anyone who entered "Ministry of External Affairs?" If so, what was the result?